# Fetching Video Feed From youtube client api

Tags: java, youtube-api

I am using the gdata-src.java-1.47.1 java client api and using the online [developer guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java). My problem is that in the online developer guide the `getFeed (URL,String)` method is called from a service instance to fetch the video feed e.g

```
 VideoFeed videoFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(feedUrl), VideoFeed.class);
```

I am assuming that the service instance is of the YouTubeService class. But when I create a instance of this class there isn't any `getFeed (URL,String)` method. What class does this method belong to or what other alternatives can I use to fetch the `VideoFeed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you importing the right JARs? I'm not sure how you're getting this error.

I imported these JARs:

```
gdata-client-1.0.jar
gdata-core-1.0.jar
gdata-youtube-2.0.jar
guava-11.0.2.jar
mail.jar
gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar
gdata-media-1.0.jar
gdata-youtube-meta-2.0.jar
jsr305.jar
```

When you unzip the GData zip file, these are found in gdata/java/lib. The dependencies are found in gdata/java/deps, and mail.jar is [found here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html).

I have these imports:

```
import com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeService;
import com.google.gdata.data.geo.impl.GeoRssWhere;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.MediaKeywords;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.MediaPlayer;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.MediaThumbnail;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.VideoEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.VideoFeed;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.YouTubeMediaContent;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.YouTubeMediaGroup;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.YouTubeMediaRating;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.YtPublicationState;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.YtStatistics;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;
```

My code is below. I'm omitting the print functions. Also, I am using ClientLogin for simplicity of the sample code - [do not use ClientLogin in a real application](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/03/clientlogin-fail.html)

```
    String feedUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed";

    YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("youtube", "DEVELOPER_KEY_HERE");
    service.setUserCredentials("LOGIN@gmail.com", "YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE");
    VideoFeed videoFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(feedUrl), VideoFeed.class);
    printVideoFeed(videoFeed, true);
```

Note that if possible, you should be looking at the [v3 API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/).

Answer (score -1):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/

Download**gdatayoutubemeta20jar**.htm

Similarly you will find all the JARs on the same page  - Click the page and download the jar.ZIP file

I am not sure, why these libs are not available for download straight away